# IntelliJ IDEA cannot commit library sources to svn

Tags: android, svn, intellij-idea

I've been using Eclipse for many years and now I'm trying IntelliJ IDEA for Android development.

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 12 Community Edition.

I do VCS-->Enable Control Integration, choose Subversion from the drop-down list.

After this step I am able to commit my main module all right. But, I cannot commit the contents of the Library module. The only option I've got is to commit the gen folder (see screenshot). And I want to be able to commit the src, libs and res folders. But they are not an option.

[image]

I've checked the Ignored Files in Project Settings, read the docs, googled, created many new svn projects, I deleted my Project and recreated it many times, and I'm still not able to commit the sources of the Library module.

Any help or hint would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try to add all the VCS roots manually in `Preferences` | `Version Control` instead of using the default setting (`<Project>`).

Comment: Did Add VCS Directory Mappings, tried both options: Project and Directory. After this, the Library module has the option commit and the same problem, while the Main Module has the option Subversion-->Share Directory available. So the problem remains, the commit dialog for the Library Module does not show the source folders.

Answer (score 1):

After disconnecting the Project from svn I checked the Project folders for hidden files, and found a remaining .svn folder in the Library's directory. After deleting the .svn folder I am able now to commit the Library's sources.